# Reduce fontsize beamer sidebar

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I want to reduce the font size of my beamer sidebar in the berkeley theme because is not enough for all my sections. How can I save some space to fit all my titles?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Corrected answer with respect to @Gonzales Medinas comment:**

Just set the beamer fonts `...section in sidebar`.

```
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
```

With the first parameter of fontsize you can change the size of the font and with the second one the distance between the elements.

---

**Original answer:**

You have to set the beamer templates `section in sidebar` and `section in sidebar shaded` (change `\fontsize{2}{2}` to your liking). Probably it also makes sense to reduce the `vksip` between the sections. This can be done in the `beamer@sidebarformat` macro. I also added this to the MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@sidebarformat#1#2#3{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,leftskip=#1,rightskip=1ex plus1fil,vmode]{#2}
    \vbox{}%
    #3\par%
    \vbox{}%
    \vskip-3ex% Change vskip between section here 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar}{\fontsize{2}{2} \selectfont \insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar shaded}{\fontsize{2}{2} \selectfont \insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    Frame 1
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    Frame 2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
    Frame 3
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
    Frame 4
\end{frame}

\section{Section 5}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5}
    Frame 5
\end{frame}

\section{Section 6}
\begin{frame}{Frame 6}
    Frame 6
\end{frame}

\section{Section 7}
\begin{frame}{Frame 7}
    Frame 7
\end{frame}

\section{Section 8}
\begin{frame}{Frame 8}
    Frame 8
\end{frame}

\section{Section 9}
\begin{frame}{Frame 9}
    Frame 9
\end{frame}

\section{Section 10}
\begin{frame}{Frame 10}
    Frame 10
\end{frame}

\section{Section 11}
\begin{frame}{Frame 11}
    Frame 11
\end{frame}

\section{Section 12}
\begin{frame}{Frame 12}
    Frame 12
\end{frame}

\section{Section 13}
\begin{frame}{Frame 13}
    Frame 13
\end{frame}

\section{Section 14}
\begin{frame}{Frame 14}
    Frame 14
\end{frame}

\section{Section 15}
\begin{frame}{Frame 15}
    Frame 15
\end{frame}

\section{Section 16}
\begin{frame}{Frame 16}
    Frame 16
\end{frame}

\section{Section 17}
\begin{frame}{Frame 17}
    Frame 17
\end{frame}

\section{Section 18}
\begin{frame}{Frame 18}
    Frame 18
\end{frame}

\section{Section 19}
\begin{frame}{Frame 19}
    Frame 19
\end{frame}

\section{Section 20}
\begin{frame}{Frame 20}
    Frame 20
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To change the font size there's no need toredefine the whole templates, it's enough (and much shorter and intuitive, in my point of view) to just change the font templates, as in `\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{2}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar shaded}{size=\fontsize{2}{2}\selectfont}`.

Comment: You are definitely right. I tried that first and totally forgot the `\selectfont` so it didn't work.