# Reduce section, subsection font size in beamer sidebar

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I have the same problem listed here:

[Reduce fontsize beamer sidebar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250836/reduce-fontsize-beamer-sidebar)

Except the given answer there does not work. Thanks to the rules here at Stack Exchange, I am not allowed to post any comments asking the person who posted the answer there to clarify their example.

I am using the following settings in my beamer:

```
\usetheme[left]{Marburg} 
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar shaded}{size=\fontsize{2}{2}\selectfont}
```

With the intention being to reduce the font size of the sections and subsections listed in the sidebar. However, these commands do not do anything. Is there an explanation or example of how they are supposed to be used in order to adjust the font size?

This also has no effect:

`\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\tiny}`

maybe the default font size is already `tiny`?

edit: Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[left]{Marburg} %  width=
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar shaded}{size=\fontsize{2}{2}\selectfont}
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}{}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, `tiny` is the default value, which you can look up in `beamerfontthemedefault.sty`, I guess your commands are right, bigger fonts seems to work. But could you please make your code compilable  with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: btw, `tiny` is already pretty small, do you think your sections will be readable if you go for smaller font? If its a problem to fit them in the sidebar, you could always give a short version for the sidebar `\section[short version]{long version}`

Comment: I have updated w/ an example. I'm reporting 100+ figures, meant to be viewed on-screen/fullscreen, not as a presentation, so even the `tiny` font size is larger than needed. I wanted the sidebar to function more like a file-tree, so I need space for many entries. Maybe even showing only subsections for the current section, and listing the subsections in 2 columns, if possible. For now smaller text size would be a good start. I can make it larger e.g. `\fontsize{20}`, but nothing less than 1 or 2 seems to have an effect.

Comment: Also, `\usetheme[left,width=8cm]{Marburg}` adjusts the width nicely. So its the vertical space that needs management.

Comment: Check the .log file: ``LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available. size <5> substituted on input line 15.``

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: I ultimately scrapped the whole idea and have been using [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) instead, it now includes a better Table of Contents at the expense of using HTML output format instead of PDF.

Answer (score 1):

## Font size

TeX is quite obstinate regarding font size. It suggests you to apply the font size that is available, and would not like to rescale its fonts.

If you do want to rescale fonts like what we did in MS word, we could use the fonts that we used in MS word. In some sense, those fonts are designed to be rescaled.

[image]

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[left]{Marburg} %  width=
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{2}{4}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar shaded}{size=\fontsize{2}{2}\selectfont}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}\setsansfont{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}{}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Showing only current section's subsections

There is a **<sub><sup>BEAMER</sup></sub>** option called `hideothersubsections` that hids other section's subsection.

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usetheme[left]{Marburg}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1-1}
    \begin{frame}
        test \\[6cm]
        test
    \end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1-2}
    \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 1-3}
    \frame{}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2-1}
    \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2-2}
    \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2-3}
    \frame{}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3-1}
    \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3-2}
    \frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3-3}
    \frame{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the desired solution, I found these alternatives, which will probably work as a substitute.

First, using code I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/customizing-the-sidebar-in-beamer) to insert slides into the document that give a Table of Contents for just the current section and its subsections

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}

...

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
...
```

The second alternative, which I like even better, is to have the sidebar only show the subsections for the section I am currently on. This is accomplished using the following code that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51647/show-hide-the-sections-subsections-and-subsections-that-i-want-from-the-navigat);

```
\usetheme[left,hideothersubsections]{Marburg}
```

In this case, some of the subsections still run off the bottom of the sidebar, but it works well enough that I might leave it unless anyone else has a solution that can reduce the font size further.